# TabularMSA replacement for Alignment (scikit-bio 0.4.1.dev0)

Tags: skbio

I would like to read a PHYLIP alignment (FASTA format), update the sequence labels and write results back to a file. How can I edit the following lines to use [TabularMSA](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/blob/master/skbio/alignment/_tabular_msa.py) in scikit-bio 0.4.1.dev0 (instead of Alignment which was supported earlier):

`from skbio import Alignment
    ...
    msa_fa = Alignment.read(gene_msa_fa_fp, format='fasta')
    msa_fa_update_ids, new_to_old_ids = msa_fa.update_ids(func=id_mapper)
    msa_fa_update_ids.write(output_msa_phy_fp, format='phylip')
    ...`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading a FASTA file into a `TabularMSA` object, sequence identifiers are stored in each sequence's `metadata` dictionary under key `"id"`. When writing a `TabularMSA` object in PHYLIP format, the MSA's `index` property is used to label the sequences. Use `reassign_index` to use the FASTA sequence identifiers as the MSA's index, then map those to the sequence labels you want written, and finally write out in PHYLIP format:

```python
from skbio import TabularMSA, DNA
msa = TabularMSA.read("aln.fasta", constructor=DNA)
msa.reassign_index(minter='id')
msa.reassign_index(mapping=id_mapper)
msa.write('aln.phy', format='phylip')
```

There are a variety of ways to set the index, including setting the property directly or using `reassign_index` with either `mapping` or `minter` parameters.

Comment: This solution works well for me, the only thing to modify was 'DNA' to 'Protein' as I was working with protein sequences. Thanks!